Action of Adams operations on $K_*(K)$
Any k-theory cooperation $K_*(K)$ can be uniquely expressed as some finite Laurent series $f(u,v)$ with certain generators $u,v$ arising from the left and right action of $\pi_*(K)$. That I understand.
It is viewed as some kind of standard fact that any stable Adams operation $\psi^k$ acts on the degree zero part via $u^nv^{-n}\mapsto k^nu^nv^{-n}$. (Actually, there is some other talk in the paper by Adams, Harris and Switzer which confuses me even more.) I am currently unable to relate this to the axiomatic definition via additivity, multiplicativity and line bundles. Can someone smarter than me explain?
Note. I have to note here that I do not understand spectral sequences. So if the answer has to do with them it just means "You shall not pass" to me.
